# filter only visible radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, validation

I have a form which has lots of fields both hidden and visible. Currently I am trying to validate the form. 
I am able to select all the radio buttons and validate it on submit using the below code.

```
$('button').click(function(){
var requiredgroups = ['radio1','radio2'];
var returnVal = true;
$.each(requiredgroups, function(id, name){
    var $radios = $('input[name="' + name + '"]:radio');
    $radios.last().next('div.error').remove();
    if(!$radios.filter(':checked').length){
        returnVal = false;
        $radios.last().after('<div class="error">Please select to continue.</div>');
    }
    else{
        returnVal = true;
        $radios.last().next('div.error').remove();

    }
});
});
```

Now I have 2 conditions - 
1. How can I filter out only the visible radio buttons on the form and display an error message. 
2. If the user fills in the form I need to remove that error message when the focus moves from the field(text box and radio). For text box I tried to do like this. But its not working. Below code is for validating all the required text boxes

```
$('#submit_form .required').filter(':visible').each(function () {
    // Code for displaying he error message
```

});

Removing the error from text box on blur of the field

```
$('#check1').blur(function(){
$.validateName();   
});
```

Can anyone please help me in this

Answer (score 0):

All you need here is

```
 $('#submit_form .required:visible').each(function () {
        // Code for displaying he error message
    });
```

and the code for revalidation

```
$('#submit_form .required:visible').on("focusout", function(){
// Code for validdation
})
```